# Composing a message in Ubuntu Touch Messaging App

Tags: ubuntu-touch

I have ubuntu touch installed on a Nexus 5 phone using multirom.

I can't imagine how this isn't a stupid question, but how do you compose a message in the messaging app? I can receive text messages, and I can send them if I select a contact from the contacts app. For the life of me I can't find out how to create a new sms message to an arbitrary number.

I've tried variants on the below google searches. Most of the results are either "how to send SMS from Ubuntu server" or "how to interface with SMS on ubuntu-sdk".

Thanks in advance,

[how to compose message ubuntu touch](https://www.google.com/search?client=ubuntu&channel=fs&q=how+to+compose+message+ubuntu+touch&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8#safe=off&channel=fs&q=how+to+compose+messaging+sms+ubuntu+touch)

[ubuntu touch sms](https://www.google.com/search?client=ubuntu&channel=fs&q=how+to+compose+message+ubuntu+touch&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8#safe=off&channel=fs&q=sms+ubuntu+touch)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aha. After giving the phone to our resident text-a-holic and asking her to see if she could send a text message she found the answer.

To create an sms message in the messaging app just swipe from the bottom of the screen to the top.

For posterity, some pictures:

[it looks just like a small white box on the bottom of the screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qyij7.png)

[if you tap on the white box, it'll say "create new"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nmh6P.png)

swiping up: i.imgur.com/F3IX4l4.png

voila!!: i.imgur.com/A3Ewdj1.png